# Is it reasonable to mutate the event.target.value

Tags: javascript

I want strip extra whitespace from between words, and I'm doing it like so:

```
const value = e.target.value.replace(/\s+/g, " ");
```

However, is this bad form and should be doing it like this:

```
const value = e.target.value
const strippedValue = value.replace(/\s+/g, " ");
```

Comment: The `replace()` function doesn't mutate anything, it returns a new string.

Comment: So the two codes are equivalent.

Comment: On top of that, your second approach creates an additional variable. Micro-optimization wise it creates a wee bit of an overhead but that’s insignificant. Pick whatever that makes sense to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are exactly the same since `replace` will return a new string and it won't mutate the `value`. FYI `Strings` are immutable in JS.

[Read more about replace from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

> The replace() method returns a new string with some or all matches of
> a pattern replaced by a replacement.

**1)**

```
const value = e.target.value.replace(/\s+/g, " ");
```

You are returning a new string with the text replace with `" "`.

**2)**

```
const value = e.target.value
const strippedValue = value.replace(/\s+/g, " ");
```

First, you are assigning the value to a variable `value` and then replace the value with `" "` and assign the result back to `strippedValue`.

Answer (score 2):

Per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

> The replace() method returns a new string with some or all matches of a pattern replaced by a replacement. The pattern can be a string or a RegExp, and the replacement can be a string or a function to be called for each match. If pattern is a string, only the first occurrence will be replaced.
>
> The original string is left unchanged.

Since `String.prototype.replace` does not mutate the original string, only returning a new one, it isn't "bad form" to directly call it upon the `event.target.value`. I would consider creating an unnecessary variable "bad form".